# security and authentication protocols

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I was researching the topic of authentication protocols, specifically protocols that work well with JAVA and REST API, and had a question regarding the subject.
The architecture of the required system is a simple client - server.

I found a few helpful protocols like 2 legged OAuth, digest authentication, Amazons S3 protocol and of course SSL.

I'm a beginner at this authentication business, and I don't quite understand why should we use all the other protocols there are out there instead of using just SSL?

It has been said that SSL is allegedly slower, but I understood that was the case a long time ago, and nowadays this protocol doesn't have this problem. 
It is also confusing to me that all the other protocols ride on SSL anyway.

I know that SSL blocks replay attacks and man in the middle attacks. 
How is SSL different, or not sufficient, in comparison to the protocols above? And what each protocol contributes that is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe 2 different requirements. You can apply to your application one of them or both of them:

1)  A data protection

2)  An authentication

The data protection means the confidentiality, the content integrity, replay attacks and man in the middle attacks and more. All these features can be achieved by SSL. SSL can be applied almost to all protocols.

The authentication means that you want to control who access your application.
There are plenty protocols, and you should select the authentication protocol depend on your requirements and time you want to invest in the authentication. Please consider OAuth2.

In addition, client authentication is optional in SSL.
The client authentication in SSL is performed using a client certificate (Generally it is X.509 certificates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)
Look Client-Certificate Authentication:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html

The client certificate is most secured authentication but most expensive from the infrastructure investment. At least it requires PKI infrastructure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure in your organization.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Ok so I understand now that SSL can only take care of the security part, but not the authentication part, But what do you mean by a client certificate? Do you refer to the certificate in the OAuth protocol (Including the time-stamp and/or nonce and token)? And when you say that the certificate uses SSL, in what way?.. These things aren't that clear to me.

Comment: I have updated the answer - please look it once again. The client certificate is not related to OAuth token.

Comment: thanks! that was helpful, I accepted the answer but can't promote because i don't have enough reputation yet. one more thing, when you're talking about client authentication, you're talking about authenticating the web application or the user himself? This term often gets confused. when we're talking about authentication, are we talking about username+password? or something more complex like recognizing private keys from the client side? or both?

Comment: Authentication is identifying a principal access your application. For most protocols (Digest, Basic, Form authentication) it is username plus password.  For the client authentication – it is validation of the client side certificate and the extracting of the information from the client certificate.